# Example of worst case distributions for 4D convex hull

Tags: convex-polytopes, computer-science, computational-geometry

My understanding is that convex hull of n points in 4D could have O(n²) edges in the worst case. Source: [https://sites.cs.ucsb.edu/~suri/cs235/ConvexHull.pdf](https://sites.cs.ucsb.edu/%7Esuri/cs235/ConvexHull.pdf)

This same source writes

> In 4D, there are n points in general
> position so that the edge joining every
> pair of points is on the convex hull!

But I can't seem to demonstrate this in practice. I tried the follow distributions of points:

- Gaussian distribution (e.g., `V = randn(n,4)`)
- Uniform distribution in box (e.g., `V = rand(n,4)`)
- Uniform distribution on 3-sphere (e.g., `V=normalize_each(randn(n,4));`)

The 3-sphere lead to the worst number of edges but it still empirically looks linear as I increase n.

Is there a known pathological distribution of points that really hits this quadratic behavior as n increases?

Comment: I think you want a neighborly polytope. Specifically, a [cyclic polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_polytope), which places points on the moment curve.

Comment: Excellent! Confirmed! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm making my comment an answer so this doesn't appear on unanswered lists.

The convex hull of points on the [moment curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_curve)
$$
(t, t^2, t^3, t^4)
$$
form what is known as a [cyclic polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_polytope).
This is a "neighborly polytope" with the property
(in this case with $d=4$) that every pair of vertices
is connected by an edge.